# colored image for MKMarkerAnnotationView in MapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, mapkitannotation

I am building an app for iOS, that allows the user to store images location based.
Now I want to use the latest `AnnotationView` (`MKMarkerAnnotationView`) in iOS for this, because it provides automated clustering.

My problem is, that this class needs a `glyphTintColor` if it is not provided it is set to `UIColor().red`. iOS is using this color to color the whole image with it. After that the image has just this color.
I tried setting the `glyphTintColor` to `nil` but this will cause the image to be red. I also tried to set it to `UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:0.0)` but after that the image is gone and you can only see the marker itself.

I want the marker to show the image in its original colors not single color.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Here is my full code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let identifier = "PinAnnotationIdentifier"

    var pinView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

    pinView?.annotation = annotation
    pinView?.clusteringIdentifier = "clusterId"
    pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)


    pinView?.canShowCallout = false
    pinView?.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "image")


    return pinView
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When you call

```
pinView?.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "image")
```

`pinView` calls

```
glyphImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

This enables an easy approach to the problem: simply override `withRenderingMode`:

```
import UIKit

class OriginalUIImage: UIImage {

    convenience init?(named name: String) {
        guard let image = UIImage(named: name),
              nil != image.cgImage else {
                    return nil
        }
        self.init(cgImage: image.cgImage!)
    }

    override func withRenderingMode(_ renderingMode: UIImage.RenderingMode) -> UIImage {
        // both return statements work:
        return self
        // return super.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    }

}
```

now you can use

```
pinView?.glyphImage = OriginalUIImage(named: "image")
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can! You just need to play with layers a little bit. 
When creating a new MKMarkerAnnotationView create UIImageView object and add layer(UIImageView) on last layer.

```
override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {

        if let cluster = newValue as? MKClusterAnnotation {
            markerTintColor = UIColor(named: "Green")
            glyphText = "\(cluster.memberAnnotations.count)"
        }

        /* Check does received value is a MapMarkerAnnotation.swift object */
        guard let mapMarkerAnnotation = newValue as? MapMarkerAnnotation else { return }

        /* Assign properties */
        markerTintColor = Application.defaultColor
        displayPriority = .required

        /* Assign image */
        if let user = mapMarkerAnnotation.userInfo as? User {
            ImageManager.get(from: user.mainPhoto) { (image) in

                let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: 24, height: 24)
                imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 24 / 2
                imageView.clipsToBounds = true
                self.layer.sublayers?[1].addSublayer(imageView.layer)

                /* Assign current image but with clear color tint. */
                self.glyphImage = image
                self.glyphTintColor = .clear
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After adding image layer. Add image layer on expanded state.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    /* Check does annotation is an **MapMarker.swift** object. */
    if let mapMarkerAnnotationView = view as? MapMarkerAnnotationView {
        if let user = mapMarkerAnnotationView.userInfo as? User {

            /* Assign image */
            ImageManager.get(from: user.mainPhoto) { (image) in

                let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: 52, height: 52)
                imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 52 / 2
                imageView.clipsToBounds = true

                /* Assign tag value */
                imageView.layer.setValue(1, forKey: "tag")

                /* check does image layer exist. */
                if mapMarkerAnnotationView.layer.sublayers?[3].sublayers?.filter({($0.value(forKey: "tag") as? Int) == 1}).count == 0 {
                    mapMarkerAnnotationView.layer.sublayers?[3].addSublayer(imageView.layer)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: For some reason, sublayers is nil sometimes, so it is not possible to assign image.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to show the image in its original colors not single color.

[glyphImage - MKMarkerAnnotationView | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmarkerannotationview/2873823-glyphimage)

> Create glyph images as template images so that the glyph tint color can be applied to it.

A glyph, also known as a template image, is a monochromatic image with transparency, anti-aliasing, and no drop shadow that uses a mask to define its shape.

Comment: Okay many thanks :) But do you think it might be possible by extending `MKMarkerAnnotationView` and creating a class, that does not set the monochromatic color? ;)

Comment: Okay many thanks ;) I think I will switch back to an old way to display images on the map ;)

Comment: I think I found a simple answer for you